# resource manager and nodemanager connectivity issues

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop3

I have hadoop cluster of 3 nodes(A,B,C), where Resource manager is running on A node and nodemanagers are running on nodes A,B,C.
I ran a simple insert command add one record to a table in hive but its taking long time to execute.
I suspect there is no inter communication between Resource Manager and Nodemangers. Checked all the ports are opened.

Error:
2024-03-20 16:16:59,353 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From dmmlw-r410-18-temp/10.173.225.159 to dmmlw-r410-23-temp:33273 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=dmmlw-r410-23-temp/10.173.225.164:33273]; For more details see:
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout
, while invoking ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers over null. Retrying after sleeping for 10000ms. Current retry count: 13.

1.Checked all the configurations files ( hdfs-site.xml,yarn-site.xml,mapred-site.xml)
2.Ports are opened between Resource manager and Nodemanagers.
3.Had enough memory and cpu to run the simple insert/aggregate (count,sum,min) operations.

Versions used: Open source Apache Hadoop 3.3.6